# Md-dialog call template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to load  template in md-dialog  when on click of button and all i see `/src/app/pages/signup/signup.html`

**Home.Controller**

```
 var vm = this;
     vm.showCustomGreeting=function($event){
           var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
           $mdDialog.show({
             parent: parentEl,
             targetEvent: $event,
             template:require('../signup/signup.html'),
             fullscreen:true,
             controller: function ControllerName($scope){
                        $scope.data = "Controller Loaded";
             },
          });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Per docs - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)

should be templateUrl, not template.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this, there is no need of require function as per now also, just make sure given template path should be right. Try this :

```
var vm = this;
 vm.showCustomGreeting=function($event){
       var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
       $mdDialog.show({
         parent: parentEl,
         targetEvent: $event,
         templateUrl:'../signup/signup.html',
         parent: angular.element(document.body),
         fullscreen:true,
         controller: function ControllerName($scope){
                    $scope.data = "Controller Loaded";
         },
      });
   }
```

Comment: i'm already use templateUrl  i get this error "Failed to load template"

Comment: Have you tried this code? i have also made one another change about required function.

Comment: yes i tried still get this error : "Failed to load template"